# How to count the number of characters in a DIV with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, count

Hi I want to be able to count the number of displayed characters in a Div with javascript/jquery. For example

```
<div id=mydiv>
<p>This is my div!</p>
</div>
```

I want to get the number 15 since that's how many chars in the div including spaces.

Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
$('#mydiv').text().length
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity of this

Comment: this is wrong, it doesnt just count the displayed text characters, it counts all the text inside div in html like tags and scripts. hoever i could not found any other way, so for this to work everything inside the div has to be a plain text (not to mention this will count whitespaces)

Comment: @SilentCave: no, it doesn't count tags. that's why there's the `.text()` call. e.g. `<p><b>foo</b></p>` and doing `$('p').text().length` will give you 3, not 10, because the `<b></b>` is NOT counted.

Comment: My bad, it actually doesn't count tags. But it does count all the script inside the div. So, i take my words.

Comment: That's to be expected. it's not up to the DOM engine to know what KIND of text is inside a tag. text is text, whether it's `hello world` or `alert('hello world')`.

Answer (score 12):

Try this. I am trimming to avoid any white spaces in the content start or end.

```
$.trim($("#mydiv").text()).length
```

If you want to keep spaces also in the count then don't trim it just use this.

```
$("#mydiv").text().length
```

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm! Actually I do want any white spaces as well, since I'm making a "read more" "read less" div, as long as the text expands the div to certain height, I will put the read more button at the end. So white space is OK if it's part of the editor's choice for formatting or style.

Answer (score 3):

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/TrMRB/

```
$("#mydiv p").text().length;
```

Comment: You actually have linebreaks in the div, too. SO it's better to access the specific element and `trim` like _ShankarSangoli_ did.

Comment: thanks, actually as long as it takes up space, white space is ok since i want the div box to be certain length then put "read more". So actually i'm more worried about some chars that does no take up space.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are searching for a Vanilla Javascript solution.

Here is one with whitespace:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#mydiv')[0].textContent.length
```

Here is one without whitespace:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#mydiv')[0].textContent.replace(/\s/g,'').length
```